# Displaying two images alternatively in one window repeatedly

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have two images. I want to show them alternatively in the same window in opencv2 again and again after 1 second(python based)

```
img = cv2.imread('LENNA.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('CAMERAMAN.jpg',0)
while TRUE:
       cv2.imshow("window",img)
       time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay
       cv2.imsow("window",img2)
```

window freezes and becomes grey when I execute this.

Comment: Awais, there seems to be an incompatibility between cv2 and sleep. See my answer below.

Comment: Folks, the question is not exactly a duplicate of that question.   What he is writing about is that it freezes when he calls sleep().   The use of sleep() with opencv() is an old problem, but it is not addressed in "Make a pause..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works.  Notice that we use `cv2.waitkey(3000)` rather than `sleep(3)`.  Aside, another way to do this would be to use animation and `imshow()` interfaces from pyplot.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('LENNA.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('CAMERAMAN.jpg',0)

while True:

    cv2.imshow("window",img)
    cv2.waitKey(3000)

    cv2.imshow("window",img2)
    cv2.waitKey(3000)
```